# Using multiple templates with the same class in C++

Tags: c++, class, templates

I have the following code in C++ -

```
template <class T>

class TempClass { 

    T value;

public: 
    TempClass(T item) 
    { 
        value = item; 
    } 

    T getValue() 
    { 
        return value; 
    } 
}; 

int main() 
{ 
    TempClass<string>* String =  
      new TempClass<string>("Rin>Sakura");


    cout << "Output Values: " << String->getValue()  
         << "\n"; 

    class TempClass<int>* integer = new TempClass<int>(9); 
    cout << "Output Values: " << integer->getValue(); 
}
```

What I would like to do is use multiple templates with the above class TempClass. I know one way of doing this is by using

```
template <class T1, class T2>
```

, but if I do that then all instances of the class must have 2 template arguments. What I want to do is something more like :

```
if (flag)
    //initialize an instance of TempClass with one template

    TempClass<string> s("haha");

else
    //initialize an instance of TempClass with 2 templates.

    TempClass<string, int> s("haha", 5);
```

Is there a way to do this without using another new class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a variadic template and an `std::tuple` to hold values of distinct types. Minimal example:

```
template<class... Ts>
class TempClass {
    using Tuple = std::tuple<Ts...>;
    Tuple values;

public: 
    TempClass(Ts... items) : values{items...} {} 

    template<std::size_t index>
    std::tuple_element_t<index, Tuple> getValue() const {
        return std::get<index>(values);
    } 
}; 

int main() {
    TempClass<int, std::string, double> tc1{0, "string", 20.19};
    std::cout << tc1.getValue<2>(); // Output: 20.19
}
```

`std::tuple_element_t` is available only since C++14. In C+11 you should be more verbose: `typename std::tuple_element<index, Tuple>::type`.

Comment: Yeah your answer seems to be what I am looking for. However I am getting an  **error: ‘tuple_element_t’ in namespace ‘std’ does not name a template type** error while running on [this](https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c++_compiler) compiler. As far as I can figure it our, it probably is an issue with the compiler.

Comment: @RijulGanguly, try `typename std::tuple_element<index, Tuple>::type`.